# SwiftUI: change delete button title in `List` editing mode

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to specify delete button title when editing list using built-in `DeleteButton` ?

Example code:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State
    private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
                    Text(user)
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func delete(source: IndexSet) { }
}
```

The code gives (when edit is active):

[image: Default delete button:]

I want to place "some_text" instead of "Delete" -- is it possible with SwiftUI? Also, is it possible to change the delete title for one single row?

Comment: It can't be done - [SwiftUI - Custom Swipe Actions In List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112426/swiftui-custom-swipe-actions-in-list)

Comment: Here is a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318584/1122517