# How can we add two custom button in swiping List - SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

[image: screenshot]

How Can I add multiple custom buttons in a list on swipe?

Comment: This is not supported in swiftUI at the moment check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112426/swiftui-custom-swipe-actions-in-list

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipeActions, but are only supported for target iOS >=15

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `swipeActions` modifier (iOS 15.0+), here is the example:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text("Item N\(item)")
    }
    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            print("Delete")
        } label: {
            Text("Delete")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .tint(.red)
        
        Button(role: .cancel) {
            print("Edit")
        } label: {
            Text("Edit")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .tint(.gray)

    }
}
```