# SwiftUI List Items implement swipe multiple actions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swipe, swiftui-list

Is multiple actions not yet supported with SwiftUI when swipe List items?

This is really disappointed I can't find a way to implement this using SwiftUI .

Need some advices folks I really do need to implement something similar

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: ListItem gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640289/swiftui-listitem-gestures)

Comment: Here is an iOS 15.0+ solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73150999/14294561

Answer (score 1):

You can use swipe actions (supported by ios 15>)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)

```
  .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                        Button {
                            action = "Star"                      
                        } label: {
                            Label("Star", systemImage: "star.circle")
                        }
                        .tint(.yellow)
                    }
}
```

Comment: This displays the swipe action but with icon only. How can I show label along with icon in iOS 16

Comment: Did you try to instead of a Label, put a VStack with a Image and Text inside?

Comment: Yes I tried and its same. But now I found that if I increase the height of the cell it shows icon and label. so it means swift decides what to show based on height.

Comment: Nice, so that is the complete solution.